# cassandra very high cpu rate

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using Cassandra version 3.0.5, just upgraded from 3.0.4 recently.

Under the query speed of very low CPU utilization of 100%.

Look at the wather, cpu is allmost all occupied by user process:

[image]

blow is top -H info(24 cpu cores machine):

```
top - 19:54:50 up 21 days,  3:06,  7 users,  load average: 25.15, 26.44, 26.66
Tasks: 987 total,  29 running, 958 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 98.7%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni,  1.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  66068260k total, 61686668k used,  4381592k free,   423456k buffers
Swap: 50331640k total,        0k used, 50331640k free, 41947168k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                         
51174 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 96.7 26.1  90:42.09 java                                                                                                                                            
51166 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 95.1 26.1  82:13.11 java                                                                                                                                            
51179 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 93.8 26.1  93:40.75 java                                                                                                                                            
51164 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 92.8 26.1  75:29.43 java                                                                                                                                            
51171 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 92.5 26.1  91:06.15 java                                                                                                                                            
51180 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 90.2 26.1  94:27.94 java                                                                                                                                            
51173 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 89.9 26.1  86:18.13 java                                                                                                                                            
51176 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 89.5 26.1  93:53.24 java                                                                                                                                            
51168 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 87.3 26.1  83:39.00 java                                                                                                                                            
51446 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 86.6 26.1  96:57.18 java                                                                                                                                            
51455 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 85.6 26.1  68:25.76 java                                                                                                                                            
51183 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 82.7 26.1  93:11.25 java                                                                                                                                            
51181 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 82.0 26.1  93:10.51 java                                                                                                                                            
51448 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 81.0 26.1  94:01.51 java                                                                                                                                            
51444 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 79.7 26.1  95:20.24 java                                                                                                                                            
51182 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 79.4 26.1  92:09.21 java                                                                                                                                            
51449 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 78.8 26.1  93:27.02 java                                                                                                                                            
51447 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 78.4 26.1  91:46.38 java                                                                                                                                            
51453 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 77.1 26.1  87:55.30 java                                                                                                                                            
51170 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 75.2 26.1  86:45.33 java                                                                                                                                            
51445 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 73.5 26.1  95:42.81 java                                                                                                                                            
51172 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 73.2 26.1  90:37.34 java                                                                                                                                            
51452 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 72.9 26.1  94:18.97 java                                                                                                                                            
51451 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 72.2 26.1  92:12.47 java                                                                                                                                            
51178 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 71.2 26.1  93:16.02 java                                                                                                                                            
51165 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 69.6 26.1  79:04.09 java                                                                                                                                            
51169 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 66.7 26.1  78:41.26 java                                                                                                                                            
51175 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g R 63.1 26.1  94:24.96 java                                                                                                                                            
51443 cassandr  20   0 42.7g  16g 3.2g S 53.9 26.1  93:11.98 java
```

then see the thread info from jstack:

```
"SharedPool-Worker-26" #301 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff8b83362e0 nid=0xc8f8 runnable [0x00007ff8867ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseRows.hasNext(BaseRows.java:110)
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.internal.composites.CompositesSearcher$1.prepareNext(CompositesSearcher.java:130)
    at org.apache.cassandra.index.internal.composites.CompositesSearcher$1.hasNext(CompositesSearcher.java:83)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BasePartitions.hasNext(BasePartitions.java:72)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.UnfilteredPartitionIterators$Serializer.serialize(UnfilteredPartitionIterators.java:295)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.build(ReadResponse.java:134)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:127)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:123)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse.createDataResponse(ReadResponse.java:65)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand.createResponse(ReadCommand.java:289)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommandVerbHandler.doVerb(ReadCommandVerbHandler.java:47)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

or this:

```
org.apache.cassandra.utils.MurmurHash.hash3_x64_128(MurmurHash.java:191)
org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner.getHash(Murmur3Partitioner.java:181)
org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner.decorateKey(Murmur3Partitioner.java:53)
org.apache.cassandra.db.PartitionPosition$ForKey.get(PartitionPosition.java:49)
org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.PartitionerDefinedOrder.compareCustom(PartitionerDefinedOrder.java:93)
org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.compare(AbstractType.java:158)
org.apache.cassandra.db.ClusteringComparator.compareComponent(ClusteringComparator.java:166)
org.apache.cassandra.db.ClusteringComparator.compare(ClusteringComparator.java:137)
org.apache.cassandra.db.ClusteringComparator.compare(ClusteringComparator.java:126)
org.apache.cassandra.db.ClusteringComparator.compare(ClusteringComparator.java:44)
org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$Candidate.compareTo(MergeIterator.java:378)
org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.replaceAndSink(MergeIterator.java:266)
org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.advance(MergeIterator.java:189)
org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.computeNext(MergeIterator.java:158)
org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47)
org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIterators$UnfilteredRowMergeIterator.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIterators.java:428)
org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIterators$UnfilteredRowMergeIterator.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIterators.java:288)
org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47)
org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseRows.hasNext(BaseRows.java:108)
org.apache.cassandra.index.internal.composites.CompositesSearcher$1.prepareNext(CompositesSearcher.java:130)
org.apache.cassandra.index.internal.composites.CompositesSearcher$1.hasNext(CompositesSearcher.java:83)
org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BasePartitions.hasNext(BasePartitions.java:72)
org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.UnfilteredPartitionIterators$Serializer.serialize(UnfilteredPartitionIterators.java:295)
org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.build(ReadResponse.java:134)
org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:127)
org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:123)
org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse.createDataResponse(ReadResponse.java:65)
org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand.createResponse(ReadCommand.java:289)
org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommandVerbHandler.doVerb(ReadCommandVerbHandler.java:47)
org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:67)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164)
org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136)
org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I find the busy running threads are all from "`SharedPool-Worker`".

They are all in `org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseRows.hasNext` or deeper than the method.

Any one encountered this problem? Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Not a cassandra problem, it's my fault of using secondary index.
I found in my application has this cql: SELECT * FROM userlabel where phone = ''.
This cql will select out too many row because of many empty phone in table "userlabel" and they are indexed.
It also may be the main reason of issue "Stack overflow when querying 2ndary index" CASSANDRA-11304, because too many row need to be queried and then occur error via recursion invoke.